# Why firefox is cutting off the placeholder text

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've an issue in Firefox browser, it is cut off a little bit from the placeholder text. Please check the below link for a snapshot.

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35853519/placeholder-cutoff.png]

Any help please?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show your HTML and CSS? A fiddle(jsfiddle.net) would be better.

Comment: try to add `line-height` property on input field.

Comment: Yes add a [JSFiddle](jsfiddle.net) please! It would help a lot!

Comment: Thanks all, solved with line-height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
input {
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

From the pic it looks like it needs more room for your text.

Comment: The line height of the placeholder psuedo-element may also need adjusting in some cases. The psuedo-element can be styled like so: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-css3-placeholder-pseudo-element